# Array of class objects in Python 3.4

Tags: python, arrays, list

How do i declare an array of class objects in Python 3.4? In C++ i can do it easily such a way:

```
class Segment
{
public:

    long int left, right;

    Segment()
    {
        left = 0;
        right = 0;
    }

    void show_all()
    {
        std::cout << left << " " << right << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const int MaxN = 10;
    Segment segment[MaxN];

    for(int i = 0; i < MaxN; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> segment[i].left;
        std::cin >> segment[i].right;
    }
}
```

In Python i have almost the same but can not find a way to create a list of class' objects and iterate through it as in C++.

```
class Segment:

    def __init__(self):
        self.left = 0
        self.right = 0

    def show_all(self):
        print(self.left, self.right)

segment = Segment()
```

So how to make such a list?

Comment: `segmentList = [Segment() for i in range(10)]` you can read up more on List comprehensions here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Thanks @Ashwin, it works as needed. I was a bit confused with python docs, but now it's clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a list.

```
segments = [Segment() for i in range(MaxN)]
for seg in segments:
    seg.left = input()
    seg.right = input()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it the same way you would make an array of any other thing in Python?

```
mylist = []
for i in range(0,10):
    mylist.append(Segment())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need it as a class like your c++ example you can do it like this:

```
class Single():
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left=left
        self.right=right

class CollectionOfSingles():
    def __init__(self, SingleObjects):
        self.singles = list(SingleObjects) #the cast here is to indicate that some checks would be nice
```

which used would look something like:

```
>>> a = Single("a", "b")
>>> b = Single("c", "d")
>>> c = Single("e", "f")
>>> objectarray = CollectionOfSingles([a, b, c])
>>> objectarray.singles
[<__main__.Single object at 0x00000000034F7D68>, <__main__.Single object at 0x00000000035592E8>, <__main__.Single object at 0x0000000003786588>]
```

and you could also append additional ones directly:

```
>>> objectarray.singles.append(Single("g", "d"))
>>> objectarray.singles
[<__main__.Single object at 0x00000000034F7D68>, <__main__.Single object at 0x00000000035592E8>, <__main__.Single object at 0x0000000003786588>, <__main__.Single object at 0x0000000003786828>]
```

implementing `__repr__` or `__str__` helps make the print nicer.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy - you could just create an iterable of `N` elements and convert them to your `Segment` class using list comprehensions:

```
In [17]: [Segment() for x in range(10)]
Out[17]: 
[<__main__.Segment at 0x7faff42c1c88>,
 <__main__.Segment at 0x7faff42c1ef0>,
 <__main__.Segment at 0x7faff42c1cf8>,
 <__main__.Segment at 0x7faff42c1630>,
 <__main__.Segment at 0x7faff42c13c8>,
 <__main__.Segment at 0x7faff4234b00>,
 <__main__.Segment at 0x7faff4234cf8>,
 <__main__.Segment at 0x7faff4234ac8>,
 <__main__.Segment at 0x7faff4234a90>,
 <__main__.Segment at 0x7faff4234b70>]
```

Not so interesting, let's show them!

```
In [18]: for s in [Segment() for x in range(10)]:
   ....:     s.show_all()
   ....:     
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
```

Whoa, they are all equal to `(0, 0)`. Wouldn't you like to add parameters to your `__init__` function?

```
In [19]: class Segment:
     ...     def __init__(self, left, right):
     ...         self.left = left
     ...         self.right = right
     ...     def __repr__(self):
     ...         return '({left}; {right})'.format(left=self.left, right=self.right)
     ...     def show_all(self):
     ...         print(self.left, self.right)
   ....:
```

You could also notice the `__repr__` function - it is used, when Python wants to show an object to us - you could read about it more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

So, let's create some segments again!

```
In [23]: [Segment(l, r) for l, r in zip(range(10), range(10, 0, -1))]
Out[23]: 
[(0; 10),
 (1; 9),
 (2; 8),
 (3; 7),
 (4; 6),
 (5; 5),
 (6; 4),
 (7; 3),
 (8; 2),
 (9; 1)]
```